# [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have been searching this issue for last few days.

In my file .h I put this in the interface:

```
NSMutableArray *newsCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newsCount;
```

And in my file .m I have wrore this piece of code.

I have alloc this in view Will Appear method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
self.newsCount = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [self.newsCount count];
       //    return 5;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@",[[newsCount objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"RELATED_CAPTION"]];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13]];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: NSArray *newsCount; instead take NSMutableArray *newsCount;

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Can you print your newsCount Array

Comment: Provide code where u have initialized your array `newsCount`

Comment: The problem is with numberOfRowsInSection method I thin the array you are creating or intializing is in a wrong manner. Actually the compiler considering your newscount array as NSString.

Comment: the line which is using variable newsCount.

Comment: You posted 2 lines that use that variable. Which one (assuming it's one of the posted lines)?

Comment: Where are you allocating the array ? Possibly you are not allocating the array.

Comment: I allocating that in viewWillAppear method. @Midhun MP

Comment: NSLog newsCount just before the problematic statement.  You will find an NSString there, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

How are you setting `self.newsCount`?

Either you are not putting an array into `self.newsCount`, or (more likely) you are setting "`newsCount`" without `retaining` it.

Are you using `ARC`?  If not, you should be.

Comment: I have set that like this.
`newsCount = [[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance].itemNewsDetail objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"RELATED"];`

Comment: @Template09 If you don't use ARC, retain the variable!

Comment: may be you are passing string value here for newsCount i think so once check it.

Comment: I have retain it in file .h`
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newsCount;`

Comment: But you are assigning to the ivar directly, not going through the retaining selector.  Use `self.newsCount = ...` (and don't use `@synthesize newsCount` at all).  Better yet, turn on ARC.

Comment: One side note is that I am pretty sure another issue you would have is that "objectForKey:@"RELATED"" would return an NSArray, not an NSMutableArray... though that would not lead to the problem you saw.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting newsCount like you mentioned in a comment on @Kendall's answer:

```
newsCount = [[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance].itemNewsDetail objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"RELATED"];
```

then the issue could be due to that object not being an NSMutableArray, but an NSString (__NSCFString is a private class used by NSString)

You might want to dump the contents of `[GlobalVariable sharedInstance].itemNewsDetail` by adding this line right after the line I mentioned earlier:

```
NSLog(@"itemNewsDetail: %@",[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance].itemNewsDetail objectAtIndex:i]);
```

and checking to see what is stored at the key `@"RELATED"`...

Comment: yap, when I do like you said for set the newsCount without the key @"RELATED"
, my numberOfRowsInSection method run well with [self.newsCount count] method..
So how I can handle it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method to show the data??

Comment: @Template09 To know that, I'd need to see the output of the NSLog statement. Can you post it [here](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: It may be more useful to log class name of the object, since that seem to be the problem, and not the contents of the object.

Comment: @MarkThalman You're right, but I think it's a bit late for that now :)